# ImportError: cannot import name 'vq'

Tags: python, seaborn

I am simply trying to import seaborn with:

```
import seaborn
```

but the error message

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'vq'
```

is thrown.
Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/XXXXX", line 13, in <module>
     import seaborn as sns
   File "D:\XXXXX\Programs\Anaconda3_4.4.0\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
     from .matrix import *
   File "D:\XXXXX\Programs\Anaconda3_4.4.0\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py", line 11, in <module>
     from scipy.cluster import hierarchy
   File "D:\XXXXX\Programs\Anaconda3_4.4.0\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
     from . import vq, hierarchy 
ImportError: cannot import name 'vq'
```

I am using: Anaconda 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)|

Comment: You need to reinstall scipy.

Comment: I have done this but this doesnt help

Comment: try: conda install seaborn or pip install seaborn

Comment: Both is not working. I have uninstalled and reinstalled seaborn trying both methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven`t figured out the cause for the error but simpy uninstall and re-install the anaconda package will fix the problem.